# xtr305 no output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, texas-instruments

I'm using [XTR305](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr305.pdf?ts=1611311650421&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FXTR305) for Analog output.
Below is the circuit for the same. After successful output from DAC which is input to XTR305, I'm not getting the output voltage. Can someone help me with that?
[image]

Comment: Do you have the thermal pad connected to V-?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes. Does XTR305 need bipolar supply?

Comment: I've combined all the error flags and used a single signal to microcontroller. Will this cause a problem?